# Filtering data with a stream that consists of a list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-stream, collect

`elementList` is a list of all elements

```
class Element{  
   private ArrayList<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<Shape>();
}
```

...

```
class Shape{
   private String color;
   private String shape;
}
```

Trying to filter a list of elements, of which each contain a list of shapes that are all different.

```
    List<Shape> roundShapes = elementList.stream()  
            .filter(x -> x.getShapeList()(})    

 //not sure what to have here.
 //I need to loop/stream the data that i get form getShapeList(). How to do this?   
 //A stream inside a stream?

            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For example find a shape that is red and round. 
The problem is i cannot just filter it directly as the data is in within a another list.

I could for loop all the elements and add each shapeList into one big list, than stream that list. But that requires a for loop and iterating over each one, and I would like to use streams instead if for loops.

Comment: What is Shapes? What is elementList? Could you post valid code for Element? What do you want your result list to contain? My guess is that you want flatMap(), but your question is unclear.

Comment: @JBNizet updated. elementList is a list that contains all elements.

Comment: Your list declaration is still invalid Java, but what you're looking for is in Bandi's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten the map and then iterate over the shapes. 

Replace the `shape.getShape().equals("Round")` with the filter criteria on shapes that you want.

```
List<Shapes> roundShapes = elementList.stream().flatMap(element -> element.getShapeList().stream())
                    .filter(shape -> shape.getShape().equals("Round")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to end up with a list of `Shape` objects collected from your `Element` objects and filtered based on some predicate, for example, red and round? If so, you could try flat - mapping the stream of `Element` objects to their `Shape` lists, and then filtering, like so:

```
<List<Shapes> roundShapes = elementList.stream()
                            .flatMap(x -> x.getShapes().stream())
                            .filter(x -> (x.getColor().equals("red") && x.getShape().equals("round")))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```